# Ина́че и и́наче

Tags: орфоэпия

В словаре Ожегова и Шведовой эти два варианта даны в рамках одной статьи. В блоке фразеологических выражений видим следующие:

```
А иначе
Иначе говоря (иначе сказать)
Не иначе как
Так или иначе
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что каждое из этих выражений можно произносить как с ударением на А, так и с ударением на И? Если руководствоваться логикой словаря, то да. Однако ухо всё-таки режет второй вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря Резниченко (2010 год):

Для местоименного наречия предлагаются два варианта: инАче и Иначе. 
Остальные выражения имеют одно ударение: вводное слово "так или инАче", в значении союза: а инАче, не инАче как.

А. С. Пушкин:

Признаться вам, я в пятистопной строчке
Люблю цезуру на второй стопе.
ИнАче стих то в яме, то на кочке.

Н. С. Гумилев: Знай, Иначе тебе помочь я не могу.